# Categorized Partial total amount from column

Tags: angularjs

Was trying to do one example by using AngularJS - here is the ngRepeat output I get from JSON data:

```
Gadgets - $45
Power Bill - $50
Gadgets - 45
Power Bill - 50
```

So I would like to get Total amount paid for Power Bill and Total Amount spent for Gadgets like 100 and 90 - How can I get this dynamically from ngRepeat using AngularJS?

Appreciate your tips and help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be useful to see the JSON data and the angular template that you used to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a controller functions to get totals and call it on click of a button.

`// Item List Arrays 

    $scope.items = [2, 3, 4]; // this can be replace by ur json data u get`

```
$scope.total = 0;
$scope.getTotal = function() { <br>

    for(var i=0; i< $scope.items.length; i++) { 

        $scope.total+= $scope.items[i];

        console.log($scope.total);
    }

}
```

// DOM

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    <div><button ng-click="getTotal()" value="get">Get Total</button>{{total}}</div>
</code>
```